# Why are "/r" characters being appended to filenames when I try to copy them?

Tags: bash, cp

I have a web server that generates GUID as filenames for JPGs stored on a web directory. Part of the GUID contains hyphens, an example would be:

```
34bc9ead-f8f0-467d-8605-df77f392da07.jpg
```

It then produces a text file stored on the server that contains all those JPGs in a list and would look like this

```
www.awebsite.com/img/34bc9ead-f8f0-467d-8605-df77f392da07.jpg
```

On a raspberry pi client, I run `wget` to get this text file and the images. I then need to copy those images to another drive.

If I run bash to read the text file, strip out the full URL so it's only the file name, and then use `cp` to copy the file it produces a strange error saying it cannot copy file "34bc9ead-f8f0-467d-8605-df77f392da07.jpg/r". Note the end of the file seems to append "/r".

Here's my code:

```bash
while read -r p; do
[[ "$p" == */* ]] || p="./$p"
b="${p##*/}"
cp $b /newdirectory/$b
done < wget_filelist.txt
sleep 5
done;
```

Just to add that I can't use `wget` to download the files to the destined directory. I use `wget` to put it in one directory and then copy the images to ram-disk to read for another job.

I thought about removing the hyphens from the file name which I can do successfully but would cause me headaches elsewhere for what I'm trying to achieve. It just seems reading a text file and passing that onto cp causes this odd "/r" to appear.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your file `wget_filelist.txt` has `DOS` style `CRLF(\r)` endings present, remove it by running

```
dos2unix wget_filelist.txt
```

and run your original `bash` script.

Comment: The carriage returns can be removed in the script too: `sed 's/\r$//' wget_file | while read ...; do ...; done`

Comment: OP is checking if $p contains a slash. If not, prepending "./" to the path.

Comment: @glennjackman: sometimes the most simplest of things make us think all sorts of complex cases.